# Swift - constant properties (e.g. strings) computed var vs let, any advantage?

Tags: swift

It is quite common to have constants, such as strings, associated with a class, say a view controller.

Is there any computational benefit to writing these constants as *computed* `var`s as opposed to constant `let`s? (Yes in practice this is over-engineering, but I am still curious.)

For example:

```
let myConstant = "myConstant"
```

Versus:

```
var myConstant: String {
    "myConstant"
}
```

My thinking is that the former is stored in memory as long as the class it is a property of exists, whereas the latter is computed every time and thus does not take up as much additional memory.

Now, if the constant is something that isn't accessed very often (for example, setting text of a label just once when the view loads), it seems to me there may be some advantage to doing it this way, but I'm not sure if actually there is no difference whatsoever or the difference is negligible.

I guess this might fall under the category of a premature optimization, but if one or the other is better practice, might as well use it since it's quite simple and would be used everywhere in a project.

The only downside I can see is the extra lines of code and additional characters.

Comment: To your premature optimization point, use the most concise and most expressive syntax until you have evidence that it's such a problem that it requires further optimization. I'd suggest `let`.

Comment: Computed variables can be defined within protocols

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp so?

Comment: There is plenty of use cases where your constants can be target-specific or protocol-implementation specific. It is a design advantage in such cases.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure I buy the presumption that the computed `String` property is necessarily more efficient re memory (esp in optimized, release builds). It could be, but not necessarily so.

Comment: That's part of what I'm asking

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but your computed property should have no memory storage for the string until it is accessed, very similarly to a lazy var.

Comment: But the function does occupy memory space, albeit not very much (although it may depend on the length of the function). That may wipe out any supposed memory benefit here. But there still may be other advantages.

Comment: Hey, you might find this link useful https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/4flh03/what_are_the_performance_cost_differences_of_let/

Comment: IMHO, the memory used by the computed property will be always greater than constant. The reason is simple, you'll have the string `myConstant` probably in your symbol table so the constant could be translated in just a pointer to the address of this string, while the computed var probably will be allocated on the stack as a function and then return the pointer to the string in the symbol table. Probably this makes a (really) small difference, and I'd assume that the compiler optimizes it when you have lots of accesses of the same address somewhat like the compiler does with collections.

Comment: @valcanaia I think that comment would constitute an answer.

Comment: By the way, while I suspect that valcanai’s observation is right, we have to remember that (a) until someone actually profiles it in an optimized build, it’s an opinion befitting of a comment (+1), not an answer; (b) string types are highly optimized behind the scenes so be careful about generalizing any conclusions; and (c) IIRC, Swift 4 (only weeks away from going into production status) is doing even more optimizations than Swift 3.

Comment: @Rob yes, this is just an opinion, I'm not sure about what I say, I just commented based on common knowledge on computer programming. I think that profiling it won't really tell us the truth, unless you have the assembly generated code for us to discuss it. The only way to know for sure would be looking into the source code of the Swift compiler rr asking Chris Lattner or any other high order member of Swift's creation :)

Comment: @valcanaia Agreed on all counts. I wasn't complaining about your comment, only quibbling about shim's suggestion that it would have been better posted as an answer. We don't want to traffic in opinions. But I think you made yourself perfectly clear and I have no complaints.

Comment: Plenty of answers on SO are opinions. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMHO, the memory used by the computed property will be always greater than the memory used by a let constant.**

The reason is simple, you'll have the string `myConstant` probably in your symbol table, so the constant could be translated in just a pointer to the address of this string, while the computed var probably will be allocated on the stack as a function and then it'd return the pointer to the string in the symbol table.

Probably this makes a (really) small difference, and I'd assume that the compiler optimizes it when you have lots of accesses of the same address, somewhat like the compiler does with collections.

I do not have any docs to verify it but I think is reasonable ir order to visualize and understand a little about what's going on when using a constant constant or a computed property var.

Comment: What if the computedProperty is not a String and is, in fact, a bigger construct (UIColor, for example?)

Comment: I think the "what" doesn't matter. The compiler can allocated anything on the symbol table. I don't know if the `swiftc` compiler does it, but I believe it is possible. Imagine converting it to C, you could simply have a `(void*)` pointer and then do what you want. And, heading back to the question, the "value returned" is the same in both cases, but the computed property carries the weight of been a function with your pros and cons, one of them I believe is that it is larger in terms of memory. What do you think?